# How to make an array and for loop with country codes and product codes

Tags: javascript, html

I have country codes and product codes and based on what set of countries are selected, the product code will be different for that set of countries compared to the other set of countries.

There are 13 total product codes which are all the default values in the drop down list below. (405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417) These are all correct product codes for countries US, CA, and PH.

So if someone selects a product code from the drop down list but is not from one of these countries, then I need to correspond the value in the product code drop down list to another value that matches for the same product in the specified country section.

There are 4 country sections (default, nfr, eu and jp)

How can I use an array to store the country codes in sections, for example:

```
var usca = ["US", "CA", "PH"];
var nfr = ["AU", "BS", "HK", "MX", "NZ", "SG", "TH"];
var eu = ["AT", "BE", "BG", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "EE"];
var jp = "JP";
```

And then retrieve the values in my else statement in my javascript function below. I don't know how to write a for loop for this.

Also, I need to stick some more else statements below the first else statement, for example:

In my JavaScript below, the product code **410** for countries AU, BS, HK, MX, NZ, SG, and TH is 485. But the same product code **410** for countries AT, BE, BG, CY, CZ, DK and EE is 605.

This is my JavaScript function and option select drop downs so far.

```
    function getCodes(){
    var countryCode = document.getElementById("country").value;
    var productCode = document.getElementById("products").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    if ((countryCode == "US") || (countryCode == "CA") || (countryCode == "PH")) {
        output.innerHTML = productCode + "&nbsp;" + countryCode;
    }else{
        if ((countryCode == "AU") || (countryCode == "BS") || (countryCode == "HK") || (countryCode == "MX") || (countryCode == "NZ") || (countryCode == "SG") || (countryCode == "TH") && (productCode == "410")) {
            productCode = "485";
            output.innerHTML = productCode + "&nbsp;" + countryCode;
        }

    }

}


<select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="#" selected="selected">Select Your Country</option>
  <option value="US">United States</option>
  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  <option value="AU">Australia</option>
  <option value="AT">Austria</option>
  <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
  <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
  <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
  <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
  <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
  <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
  <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
  <option value="FI">Finland</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
  <option value="DE">Germany</option>
  <option value="GR">Greece</option>
  <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
  <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
  <option value="IL">Israel</option>
  <option value="IT">Italy</option>
  <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
  <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
  <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
  <option value="MT">Malta</option>
  <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
  <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
  <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="NO">Norway</option>
  <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
  <option value="PL">Poland</option>
  <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
  <option value="RO">Romania</option>
  <option value="RU">Russia</option>
  <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
  <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
  <option value="SL">Slovenia</option>
  <option value="ES">Spain</option>
  <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
  <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
  <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
  <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
  <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
</select>


<select name="products" id="products">
  <option value="#" selected="selected">Select Combo Boxes</option>
  <option value="410">1 box product A</option>
  <option value="405">2 boxes product A</option>
  <option value="406">4 boxes product A</option>
  <option value="409">1 box product B</option>
  <option value="407">2 boxes product B</option>
  <option value="408">4 boxes product B</option>
  <option value="413">1 box product C</option>
  <option value="414">2 boxes product C</option>
  <option value="415">4 boxes product C</option>
  <option value="411">2 boxes product D</option>
  <option value="412">4 boxes product D</option>
  <option value="416">2 boxes product E</option>
  <option value="417">4 boxes product E</option>
</select>
```

So basically what I am trying to do is this: When a user selects a country from the drop down and then selects a product, there will be an add to cart button and when pressed will send them to a url with the correct parameters in the url for country code and product code. Problem is, the default product codes in the drop down are not the same for all countries.

What is a good solution here?

---

**Edit**

```
<script>
function getCodes(){
    var countryCode = document.getElementById("country").value;
    var productCode = document.getElementById("products").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var specialCodes = {
    AU410: '485', AU405: '480', AU406: '481', AU409: '484', AU407: '482', AU408: '483', AU413: '492', AU414: '488', AU415: '489', AU411: '486', AU412: '487', AU416: '490', AU417: '491',
    BS410: '485', BS405: '480', BS406: '481', BS409: '484', BS407: '482', BS408: '483', BS413: '492', BS414: '488', BS415: '489', BS411: '486', BS412: '487', BS416: '490', BS417: '491',
    HK410: '485', HK405: '480', HK406: '481', HK409: '484', HK407: '482', HK408: '483', HK413: '492', HK414: '488', HK415: '489', HK411: '486', HK412: '487', HK416: '490', HK417: '491',
    MX410: '485', MX405: '480', MX406: '481', MX409: '484', MX407: '482', MX408: '483', MX413: '492', MX414: '488', MX415: '489', MX411: '486', MX412: '487', MX416: '490', MX417: '491',
    NZ410: '485', NZ405: '480', NZ406: '481', NZ409: '484', NZ407: '482', NZ408: '483', NZ413: '492', NZ414: '488', NZ415: '489', NZ411: '486', NZ412: '487', NZ416: '490', NZ417: '491',
    SG410: '485', SG405: '480', SG406: '481', SG409: '484', SG407: '482', SG408: '483', SG413: '492', SG414: '488', SG415: '489', SG411: '486', SG412: '487', SG416: '490', SG417: '491',
    TH410: '485', TH405: '480', TH406: '481', TH409: '484', TH407: '482', TH408: '483', TH413: '492', TH414: '488', TH415: '489', TH411: '486', TH412: '487', TH416: '490', TH417: '491',
    JP410: '516', JP405: '516', JP406: '522', JP409: '517', JP407: '517', JP408: '523', JP413: '528', JP414: '528', JP415: '530', JP411: '521', JP412: '521', JP416: '534', JP417: '534',
    AT410: '605', AT405: '600', AT406: '601', AT409: '604', AT407: '602', AT408: '603', AT413: '605', AT414: '600', AT415: '601', AT411: '617', AT412: '618', AT416: '617', AT417: '618',
    BE410: '605', BE405: '600', BE406: '601', BE409: '604', BE407: '602', BE408: '603', BE413: '605', BE414: '600', BE415: '601', BE411: '617', BE412: '618', BE416: '617', BE417: '618',
    BG410: '605', BG405: '600', BG406: '601', BG409: '604', BG407: '602', BG408: '603', BG413: '605', BG414: '600', BG415: '601', BG411: '617', BG412: '618', BG416: '617', BG417: '618',
    CY410: '605', CY405: '600', CY406: '601', CY409: '604', CY407: '602', CY408: '603', CY413: '605', CY414: '600', CY415: '601', CY411: '617', CY412: '618', CY416: '617', CY417: '618',
    CZ410: '605', CZ405: '600', CZ406: '601', CZ409: '604', CZ407: '602', CZ408: '603', CZ413: '605', CZ414: '600', CZ415: '601', CZ411: '617', CZ412: '618', CZ416: '617', CZ417: '618',
    DK410: '605', DK405: '600', DK406: '601', DK409: '604', DK407: '602', DK408: '603', DK413: '605', DK414: '600', DK415: '601', DK411: '617', DK412: '618', DK416: '617', DK417: '618',
    EE410: '605', EE405: '600', EE406: '601', EE409: '604', EE407: '602', EE408: '603', EE413: '605', EE414: '600', EE415: '601', EE411: '617', EE412: '618', EE416: '617', EE417: '618',
    FI410: '605', FI405: '600', FI406: '601', FI409: '604', FI407: '602', FI408: '603', FI413: '605', FI414: '600', FI415: '601', FI411: '617', FI412: '618', FI416: '617', FI417: '618',
    FR410: '605', FR405: '600', FR406: '601', FR409: '604', FR407: '602', FR408: '603', FR413: '605', FR414: '600', FR415: '601', FR411: '617', FR412: '618', FR416: '617', FR417: '618',
    DE410: '605', DE405: '600', DE406: '601', DE409: '604', DE407: '602', DE408: '603', DE413: '605', DE414: '600', DE415: '601', DE411: '617', DE412: '618', DE416: '617', DE417: '618',
    GR410: '605', GR405: '600', GR406: '601', GR409: '604', GR407: '602', GR408: '603', GR413: '605', GR414: '600', GR415: '601', GR411: '617', GR412: '618', GR416: '617', GR417: '618',
    HU410: '605', HU405: '600', HU406: '601', HU409: '604', HU407: '602', HU408: '603', HU413: '605', HU414: '600', HU415: '601', HU411: '617', HU412: '618', HU416: '617', HU417: '618',
    IE410: '605', IE405: '600', IE406: '601', IE409: '604', IE407: '602', IE408: '603', IE413: '605', IE414: '600', IE415: '601', IE411: '617', IE412: '618', IE416: '617', IE417: '618',
    IT410: '605', IT405: '600', IT406: '601', IT409: '604', IT407: '602', IT408: '603', IT413: '605', IT414: '600', IT415: '601', IT411: '617', IT412: '618', IT416: '617', IT417: '618',
    LV410: '605', LV405: '600', LV406: '601', LV409: '604', LV407: '602', LV408: '603', LV413: '605', LV414: '600', LV415: '601', LV411: '617', LV412: '618', LV416: '617', LV417: '618',
    LT410: '605', LT405: '600', LT406: '601', LT409: '604', LT407: '602', LT408: '603', LT413: '605', LT414: '600', LT415: '601', LT411: '617', LT412: '618', LT416: '617', LT417: '618',
    LU410: '605', LU405: '600', LU406: '601', LU409: '604', LU407: '602', LU408: '603', LU413: '605', LU414: '600', LU415: '601', LU411: '617', LU412: '618', LU416: '617', LU417: '618',
    MT410: '605', MT405: '600', MT406: '601', MT409: '604', MT407: '602', MT408: '603', MT413: '605', MT414: '600', MT415: '601', MT411: '617', MT412: '618', MT416: '617', MT417: '618',
    NO410: '605', NO405: '600', NO406: '601', NO409: '604', NO407: '602', NO408: '603', NO413: '605', NO414: '600', NO415: '601', NO411: '617', NO412: '618', NO416: '617', NO417: '618',
    PL410: '605', PL405: '600', PL406: '601', PL409: '604', PL407: '602', PL408: '603', PL413: '605', PL414: '600', PL415: '601', PL411: '617', PL412: '618', PL416: '617', PL417: '618',
    PT410: '605', PT405: '600', PT406: '601', PT409: '604', PT407: '602', PT408: '603', PT413: '605', PT414: '600', PT415: '601', PT411: '617', PT412: '618', PT416: '617', PT417: '618',
    RO410: '605', RO405: '600', RO406: '601', RO409: '604', RO407: '602', RO408: '603', RO413: '605', RO414: '600', RO415: '601', RO411: '617', RO412: '618', RO416: '617', RO417: '618',
    SK410: '605', SK405: '600', SK406: '601', SK409: '604', SK407: '602', SK408: '603', SK413: '605', SK414: '600', SK415: '601', SK411: '617', SK412: '618', SK416: '617', SK417: '618',
    SL410: '605', SL405: '600', SL406: '601', SL409: '604', SL407: '602', SL408: '603', SL413: '605', SL414: '600', SL415: '601', SL411: '617', SL412: '618', SL416: '617', SL417: '618',
    ES410: '605', ES405: '600', ES406: '601', ES409: '604', ES407: '602', ES408: '603', ES413: '605', ES414: '600', ES415: '601', ES411: '617', ES412: '618', ES416: '617', ES417: '618',
    SE410: '605', SE405: '600', SE406: '601', SE409: '604', SE407: '602', SE408: '603', SE413: '605', SE414: '600', SE415: '601', SE411: '617', SE412: '618', SE416: '617', SE417: '618',
    CH410: '605', CH405: '600', CH406: '601', CH409: '604', CH407: '602', CH408: '603', CH413: '605', CH414: '600', CH415: '601', CH411: '617', CH412: '618', CH416: '617', CH417: '618',
    NL410: '605', NL405: '600', NL406: '601', NL409: '604', NL407: '602', NL408: '603', NL413: '605', NL414: '600', NL415: '601', NL411: '617', NL412: '618', NL416: '617', NL417: '618',
    GB410: '605', GB405: '600', GB406: '601', GB409: '604', GB407: '602', GB408: '603', GB413: '605', GB414: '600', GB415: '601', GB411: '617', GB412: '618', GB416: '617', GB417: '618'
    };
    if ((countryCode == "US") || (countryCode == "CA") || (countryCode == "PH")) {
        location.href = "url.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
    }else{
        if ( (countryCode + productCode) in specialCodes) {
            productCode = specialCodes[countryCode + productCode];
            location.href = "urlnfr.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
        }

    }

}

</script>
```

---

**Edit**

This updated script works. But let me know if your method is more efficient. What I did here was just take the specialCode array and separate it into 3 arrays, one for nfr, one for eu, and one for jp.

```
    function getCodes(){
var countryCode = document.getElementById("country").value;
var productCode = document.getElementById("products").value;

var euCodes = {
AT410: '605', AT405: '600', AT406: '601', AT409: '604', AT407: '602', AT408: '603', AT413: '605', AT414: '600', AT415: '601', AT411: '617', AT412: '618', AT416: '617', AT417: '618',
BE410: '605', BE405: '600', BE406: '601', BE409: '604', BE407: '602', BE408: '603', BE413: '605', BE414: '600', BE415: '601', BE411: '617', BE412: '618', BE416: '617', BE417: '618',
BG410: '605', BG405: '600', BG406: '601', BG409: '604', BG407: '602', BG408: '603', BG413: '605', BG414: '600', BG415: '601', BG411: '617', BG412: '618', BG416: '617', BG417: '618',
CY410: '605', CY405: '600', CY406: '601', CY409: '604', CY407: '602', CY408: '603', CY413: '605', CY414: '600', CY415: '601', CY411: '617', CY412: '618', CY416: '617', CY417: '618',
CZ410: '605', CZ405: '600', CZ406: '601', CZ409: '604', CZ407: '602', CZ408: '603', CZ413: '605', CZ414: '600', CZ415: '601', CZ411: '617', CZ412: '618', CZ416: '617', CZ417: '618',
DK410: '605', DK405: '600', DK406: '601', DK409: '604', DK407: '602', DK408: '603', DK413: '605', DK414: '600', DK415: '601', DK411: '617', DK412: '618', DK416: '617', DK417: '618',
EE410: '605', EE405: '600', EE406: '601', EE409: '604', EE407: '602', EE408: '603', EE413: '605', EE414: '600', EE415: '601', EE411: '617', EE412: '618', EE416: '617', EE417: '618',
FI410: '605', FI405: '600', FI406: '601', FI409: '604', FI407: '602', FI408: '603', FI413: '605', FI414: '600', FI415: '601', FI411: '617', FI412: '618', FI416: '617', FI417: '618',
FR410: '605', FR405: '600', FR406: '601', FR409: '604', FR407: '602', FR408: '603', FR413: '605', FR414: '600', FR415: '601', FR411: '617', FR412: '618', FR416: '617', FR417: '618',
DE410: '605', DE405: '600', DE406: '601', DE409: '604', DE407: '602', DE408: '603', DE413: '605', DE414: '600', DE415: '601', DE411: '617', DE412: '618', DE416: '617', DE417: '618',
GR410: '605', GR405: '600', GR406: '601', GR409: '604', GR407: '602', GR408: '603', GR413: '605', GR414: '600', GR415: '601', GR411: '617', GR412: '618', GR416: '617', GR417: '618',
HU410: '605', HU405: '600', HU406: '601', HU409: '604', HU407: '602', HU408: '603', HU413: '605', HU414: '600', HU415: '601', HU411: '617', HU412: '618', HU416: '617', HU417: '618',
IE410: '605', IE405: '600', IE406: '601', IE409: '604', IE407: '602', IE408: '603', IE413: '605', IE414: '600', IE415: '601', IE411: '617', IE412: '618', IE416: '617', IE417: '618',
IT410: '605', IT405: '600', IT406: '601', IT409: '604', IT407: '602', IT408: '603', IT413: '605', IT414: '600', IT415: '601', IT411: '617', IT412: '618', IT416: '617', IT417: '618',
LV410: '605', LV405: '600', LV406: '601', LV409: '604', LV407: '602', LV408: '603', LV413: '605', LV414: '600', LV415: '601', LV411: '617', LV412: '618', LV416: '617', LV417: '618',
LT410: '605', LT405: '600', LT406: '601', LT409: '604', LT407: '602', LT408: '603', LT413: '605', LT414: '600', LT415: '601', LT411: '617', LT412: '618', LT416: '617', LT417: '618',
LU410: '605', LU405: '600', LU406: '601', LU409: '604', LU407: '602', LU408: '603', LU413: '605', LU414: '600', LU415: '601', LU411: '617', LU412: '618', LU416: '617', LU417: '618',
MT410: '605', MT405: '600', MT406: '601', MT409: '604', MT407: '602', MT408: '603', MT413: '605', MT414: '600', MT415: '601', MT411: '617', MT412: '618', MT416: '617', MT417: '618',
NO410: '605', NO405: '600', NO406: '601', NO409: '604', NO407: '602', NO408: '603', NO413: '605', NO414: '600', NO415: '601', NO411: '617', NO412: '618', NO416: '617', NO417: '618',
PL410: '605', PL405: '600', PL406: '601', PL409: '604', PL407: '602', PL408: '603', PL413: '605', PL414: '600', PL415: '601', PL411: '617', PL412: '618', PL416: '617', PL417: '618',
PT410: '605', PT405: '600', PT406: '601', PT409: '604', PT407: '602', PT408: '603', PT413: '605', PT414: '600', PT415: '601', PT411: '617', PT412: '618', PT416: '617', PT417: '618',
RO410: '605', RO405: '600', RO406: '601', RO409: '604', RO407: '602', RO408: '603', RO413: '605', RO414: '600', RO415: '601', RO411: '617', RO412: '618', RO416: '617', RO417: '618',
SK410: '605', SK405: '600', SK406: '601', SK409: '604', SK407: '602', SK408: '603', SK413: '605', SK414: '600', SK415: '601', SK411: '617', SK412: '618', SK416: '617', SK417: '618',
SL410: '605', SL405: '600', SL406: '601', SL409: '604', SL407: '602', SL408: '603', SL413: '605', SL414: '600', SL415: '601', SL411: '617', SL412: '618', SL416: '617', SL417: '618',
ES410: '605', ES405: '600', ES406: '601', ES409: '604', ES407: '602', ES408: '603', ES413: '605', ES414: '600', ES415: '601', ES411: '617', ES412: '618', ES416: '617', ES417: '618',
SE410: '605', SE405: '600', SE406: '601', SE409: '604', SE407: '602', SE408: '603', SE413: '605', SE414: '600', SE415: '601', SE411: '617', SE412: '618', SE416: '617', SE417: '618',
CH410: '605', CH405: '600', CH406: '601', CH409: '604', CH407: '602', CH408: '603', CH413: '605', CH414: '600', CH415: '601', CH411: '617', CH412: '618', CH416: '617', CH417: '618',
NL410: '605', NL405: '600', NL406: '601', NL409: '604', NL407: '602', NL408: '603', NL413: '605', NL414: '600', NL415: '601', NL411: '617', NL412: '618', NL416: '617', NL417: '618',
GB410: '605', GB405: '600', GB406: '601', GB409: '604', GB407: '602', GB408: '603', GB413: '605', GB414: '600', GB415: '601', GB411: '617', GB412: '618', GB416: '617', GB417: '618'
};

var nfrCodes = {
    AU410: '485', AU405: '480', AU406: '481', AU409: '484', AU407: '482', AU408: '483', AU413: '492', AU414: '488', AU415: '489', AU411: '486', AU412: '487', AU416: '490', AU417: '491',
BS410: '485', BS405: '480', BS406: '481', BS409: '484', BS407: '482', BS408: '483', BS413: '492', BS414: '488', BS415: '489', BS411: '486', BS412: '487', BS416: '490', BS417: '491',
HK410: '485', HK405: '480', HK406: '481', HK409: '484', HK407: '482', HK408: '483', HK413: '492', HK414: '488', HK415: '489', HK411: '486', HK412: '487', HK416: '490', HK417: '491',
MX410: '485', MX405: '480', MX406: '481', MX409: '484', MX407: '482', MX408: '483', MX413: '492', MX414: '488', MX415: '489', MX411: '486', MX412: '487', MX416: '490', MX417: '491',
NZ410: '485', NZ405: '480', NZ406: '481', NZ409: '484', NZ407: '482', NZ408: '483', NZ413: '492', NZ414: '488', NZ415: '489', NZ411: '486', NZ412: '487', NZ416: '490', NZ417: '491',
SG410: '485', SG405: '480', SG406: '481', SG409: '484', SG407: '482', SG408: '483', SG413: '492', SG414: '488', SG415: '489', SG411: '486', SG412: '487', SG416: '490', SG417: '491',
TH410: '485', TH405: '480', TH406: '481', TH409: '484', TH407: '482', TH408: '483', TH413: '492', TH414: '488', TH415: '489', TH411: '486', TH412: '487', TH416: '490', TH417: '491'
};

var jpCodes = {
    JP410: '516', JP405: '516', JP406: '522', JP409: '517', JP407: '517', JP408: '523', JP413: '528', JP414: '528', JP415: '530', JP411: '521', JP412: '521', JP416: '534', JP417: '534'
};

if ((countryCode == "US") || (countryCode == "CA") || (countryCode == "PH")) {
    location.href = "url.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
}else{
    if ( (countryCode + productCode) in nfrCodes) {
        productCode = nfrCodes[countryCode + productCode];
    location.href = "urlnfr.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
    }else{
    if ( (countryCode + productCode) in euCodes) {
        productCode = euCodes[countryCode + productCode];
        location.href = "urleu.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
    }else{
        if ( (countryCode + productCode) in jpCodes) {
        productCode = jpCodes[countryCode + productCode];
        location.href = "urljp.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode + "&l=6";
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

---

**Edit**

Updated the script above to combined the Else If statements as @wavemode suggested.

**updated script**

```
    function getCodes(){
var countryCode = document.getElementById("country").value;
var productCode = document.getElementById("products").value;

var euCodes = {
AT410: '605', AT405: '600', AT406: '601', AT409: '604', AT407: '602', AT408: '603', AT413: '605', AT414: '600', AT415: '601', AT411: '617', AT412: '618', AT416: '617', AT417: '618',
BE410: '605', BE405: '600', BE406: '601', BE409: '604', BE407: '602', BE408: '603', BE413: '605', BE414: '600', BE415: '601', BE411: '617', BE412: '618', BE416: '617', BE417: '618',
BG410: '605', BG405: '600', BG406: '601', BG409: '604', BG407: '602', BG408: '603', BG413: '605', BG414: '600', BG415: '601', BG411: '617', BG412: '618', BG416: '617', BG417: '618',
CY410: '605', CY405: '600', CY406: '601', CY409: '604', CY407: '602', CY408: '603', CY413: '605', CY414: '600', CY415: '601', CY411: '617', CY412: '618', CY416: '617', CY417: '618',
CZ410: '605', CZ405: '600', CZ406: '601', CZ409: '604', CZ407: '602', CZ408: '603', CZ413: '605', CZ414: '600', CZ415: '601', CZ411: '617', CZ412: '618', CZ416: '617', CZ417: '618',
DK410: '605', DK405: '600', DK406: '601', DK409: '604', DK407: '602', DK408: '603', DK413: '605', DK414: '600', DK415: '601', DK411: '617', DK412: '618', DK416: '617', DK417: '618',
EE410: '605', EE405: '600', EE406: '601', EE409: '604', EE407: '602', EE408: '603', EE413: '605', EE414: '600', EE415: '601', EE411: '617', EE412: '618', EE416: '617', EE417: '618',
FI410: '605', FI405: '600', FI406: '601', FI409: '604', FI407: '602', FI408: '603', FI413: '605', FI414: '600', FI415: '601', FI411: '617', FI412: '618', FI416: '617', FI417: '618',
FR410: '605', FR405: '600', FR406: '601', FR409: '604', FR407: '602', FR408: '603', FR413: '605', FR414: '600', FR415: '601', FR411: '617', FR412: '618', FR416: '617', FR417: '618',
DE410: '605', DE405: '600', DE406: '601', DE409: '604', DE407: '602', DE408: '603', DE413: '605', DE414: '600', DE415: '601', DE411: '617', DE412: '618', DE416: '617', DE417: '618',
GR410: '605', GR405: '600', GR406: '601', GR409: '604', GR407: '602', GR408: '603', GR413: '605', GR414: '600', GR415: '601', GR411: '617', GR412: '618', GR416: '617', GR417: '618',
HU410: '605', HU405: '600', HU406: '601', HU409: '604', HU407: '602', HU408: '603', HU413: '605', HU414: '600', HU415: '601', HU411: '617', HU412: '618', HU416: '617', HU417: '618',
IE410: '605', IE405: '600', IE406: '601', IE409: '604', IE407: '602', IE408: '603', IE413: '605', IE414: '600', IE415: '601', IE411: '617', IE412: '618', IE416: '617', IE417: '618',
IT410: '605', IT405: '600', IT406: '601', IT409: '604', IT407: '602', IT408: '603', IT413: '605', IT414: '600', IT415: '601', IT411: '617', IT412: '618', IT416: '617', IT417: '618',
LV410: '605', LV405: '600', LV406: '601', LV409: '604', LV407: '602', LV408: '603', LV413: '605', LV414: '600', LV415: '601', LV411: '617', LV412: '618', LV416: '617', LV417: '618',
LT410: '605', LT405: '600', LT406: '601', LT409: '604', LT407: '602', LT408: '603', LT413: '605', LT414: '600', LT415: '601', LT411: '617', LT412: '618', LT416: '617', LT417: '618',
LU410: '605', LU405: '600', LU406: '601', LU409: '604', LU407: '602', LU408: '603', LU413: '605', LU414: '600', LU415: '601', LU411: '617', LU412: '618', LU416: '617', LU417: '618',
MT410: '605', MT405: '600', MT406: '601', MT409: '604', MT407: '602', MT408: '603', MT413: '605', MT414: '600', MT415: '601', MT411: '617', MT412: '618', MT416: '617', MT417: '618',
NO410: '605', NO405: '600', NO406: '601', NO409: '604', NO407: '602', NO408: '603', NO413: '605', NO414: '600', NO415: '601', NO411: '617', NO412: '618', NO416: '617', NO417: '618',
PL410: '605', PL405: '600', PL406: '601', PL409: '604', PL407: '602', PL408: '603', PL413: '605', PL414: '600', PL415: '601', PL411: '617', PL412: '618', PL416: '617', PL417: '618',
PT410: '605', PT405: '600', PT406: '601', PT409: '604', PT407: '602', PT408: '603', PT413: '605', PT414: '600', PT415: '601', PT411: '617', PT412: '618', PT416: '617', PT417: '618',
RO410: '605', RO405: '600', RO406: '601', RO409: '604', RO407: '602', RO408: '603', RO413: '605', RO414: '600', RO415: '601', RO411: '617', RO412: '618', RO416: '617', RO417: '618',
SK410: '605', SK405: '600', SK406: '601', SK409: '604', SK407: '602', SK408: '603', SK413: '605', SK414: '600', SK415: '601', SK411: '617', SK412: '618', SK416: '617', SK417: '618',
SL410: '605', SL405: '600', SL406: '601', SL409: '604', SL407: '602', SL408: '603', SL413: '605', SL414: '600', SL415: '601', SL411: '617', SL412: '618', SL416: '617', SL417: '618',
ES410: '605', ES405: '600', ES406: '601', ES409: '604', ES407: '602', ES408: '603', ES413: '605', ES414: '600', ES415: '601', ES411: '617', ES412: '618', ES416: '617', ES417: '618',
SE410: '605', SE405: '600', SE406: '601', SE409: '604', SE407: '602', SE408: '603', SE413: '605', SE414: '600', SE415: '601', SE411: '617', SE412: '618', SE416: '617', SE417: '618',
CH410: '605', CH405: '600', CH406: '601', CH409: '604', CH407: '602', CH408: '603', CH413: '605', CH414: '600', CH415: '601', CH411: '617', CH412: '618', CH416: '617', CH417: '618',
NL410: '605', NL405: '600', NL406: '601', NL409: '604', NL407: '602', NL408: '603', NL413: '605', NL414: '600', NL415: '601', NL411: '617', NL412: '618', NL416: '617', NL417: '618',
GB410: '605', GB405: '600', GB406: '601', GB409: '604', GB407: '602', GB408: '603', GB413: '605', GB414: '600', GB415: '601', GB411: '617', GB412: '618', GB416: '617', GB417: '618'
};

var nfrCodes = {
    AU410: '485', AU405: '480', AU406: '481', AU409: '484', AU407: '482', AU408: '483', AU413: '492', AU414: '488', AU415: '489', AU411: '486', AU412: '487', AU416: '490', AU417: '491',
BS410: '485', BS405: '480', BS406: '481', BS409: '484', BS407: '482', BS408: '483', BS413: '492', BS414: '488', BS415: '489', BS411: '486', BS412: '487', BS416: '490', BS417: '491',
HK410: '485', HK405: '480', HK406: '481', HK409: '484', HK407: '482', HK408: '483', HK413: '492', HK414: '488', HK415: '489', HK411: '486', HK412: '487', HK416: '490', HK417: '491',
MX410: '485', MX405: '480', MX406: '481', MX409: '484', MX407: '482', MX408: '483', MX413: '492', MX414: '488', MX415: '489', MX411: '486', MX412: '487', MX416: '490', MX417: '491',
NZ410: '485', NZ405: '480', NZ406: '481', NZ409: '484', NZ407: '482', NZ408: '483', NZ413: '492', NZ414: '488', NZ415: '489', NZ411: '486', NZ412: '487', NZ416: '490', NZ417: '491',
SG410: '485', SG405: '480', SG406: '481', SG409: '484', SG407: '482', SG408: '483', SG413: '492', SG414: '488', SG415: '489', SG411: '486', SG412: '487', SG416: '490', SG417: '491',
TH410: '485', TH405: '480', TH406: '481', TH409: '484', TH407: '482', TH408: '483', TH413: '492', TH414: '488', TH415: '489', TH411: '486', TH412: '487', TH416: '490', TH417: '491'
};

var jpCodes = {
    JP410: '516', JP405: '516', JP406: '522', JP409: '517', JP407: '517', JP408: '523', JP413: '528', JP414: '528', JP415: '530', JP411: '521', JP412: '521', JP416: '534', JP417: '534'
};

if ((countryCode == "US") || (countryCode == "CA") || (countryCode == "PH")) {
    location.href = "url.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
}else   if ( (countryCode + productCode) in nfrCodes) {
    productCode = nfrCodes[countryCode + productCode];
    location.href = "urlnfr.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
}else   if ( (countryCode + productCode) in euCodes) {
    productCode = euCodes[countryCode + productCode];
    location.href = "urleu.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
}else   if ( (countryCode + productCode) in jpCodes) {
    productCode = jpCodes[countryCode + productCode];
    location.href = "urljp.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode + "&l=6";
}
}
```

Comment: You can combine `else { if {` into a simple `else if {`

Comment: thanks I was wondering about that @wavemode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely have to manually input all the special combinations into an array, and check against that like so:

```js
/* store all special combinations here */
var specialCodes = {
    AU410: '485',
    BS410: '485',
    HK410: '485'
    /* etc */
};
/* check if the user's combination is a special case */
if ( (countryCode + productCode) in specialCodes) {
    productCode = specialCode[countryCode + productCode];
}
```

**EDIT:** You can use a similar technique for specifying special URLs based on country. Create an object with the special URLs by country:

```
/* put special url changes here */
var urls = {
    AU: "urlnrf.com",
    EE: "urleu.com",
    JP: "urljp.com"
    /* etc */
};

if ("US CA PH".indexOf(countryCode) >= 0) { 
    location.href = "url.com?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
}else{
    if ( (countryCode + productCode) in specialCodes) {
        productCode = specialCodes[countryCode + productCode];

        /* url is set to urls[countryCode] if it exists, otherwise "url.com" */
        location.href = (urls[countryCode] || "url.com") + "?a=" + productCode + "&c=" + countryCode;
    }

}
```

Comment: I will implement this and let you know if it all works. I'll repost the code afterwards.

Comment: Everything works but now the issue is I can not differentiate the unique urls for the 4 country sections. And the else statement is referencing the specialCodes array where all of the country codes and product codes are at.

for example: the default country codes have a unique url of //url.com/
the nfr country sections AU, BS, HK, MX, NZ, SG, and TH use url //urlnfr.com/
and the eu country sections AT, BE, BG, CY, CZ, DK and EE use url //urleu.com/
and the jp country section JP uses url //urljp.com/

As it is right now, everything in the specialCode array is using //urlnfr.com/

Comment: Could you update your question with the code you're talking about to clarify?

Comment: Yes I tried to update it with the code but it is not letting me post it. It kept saying invalid code and I made sure it was indented 4 spaces. I'll try again.

Comment: I updated the JavaScript code in my original question above. Thanks @wavemode

Comment: ok got it, that is definitely a way to do it. I actually just added a few other arrays to hold the nfr, eu and jp separately. I'll update the JavaScript code above so you can see. But if your way is more efficient, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah your way works well. I understand now how your application categorizes all the codes by region, so your way is just fine.